# Decent tutorial needed for setting up simple MySQL client-server system

Tags: server, mysql

1. Could anyone please comment what I have missed during Ubuntu setup, that I am allowed to nothing on my system? Always needing to sudo from command line is not practical if you are not familiar with linux syntax, some things I just want to do the graphical way.

[image]

2. Could anyone point me to comprehensive tutorial on setting up a SIMPLE mysql-5.5 client-server system. Server: Ubuntu virtual machine, Client: Windows.

No special requirements, just want to replace our current MS Access database by something more decent.

I have done my research, have studied official mysql documentation, but it is not a step-by-step guide. For example it doesn't tell you from the start that bind-address must be edited to allow access from the Windows client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could anyone please comment what I have missed during Ubuntu setup, that I am allowed to nothing on my system?

You wont be able to edit `my.cnf` because its protected by its permissions from regular users writing to it. You could change the permissions or the group of the file but this really isn't necessary and could compromise security.

Like you have mentioned you have to use `sudo gedit /etc/mysql/my.cnf` to be able to open the file for writing.

if you really want to use the gui to edit these files without touching the command line you can use `gksudo` by installing `gksu` from the software centre.

Then you can launch `gksudo` the same way you can any other gui app. It will then ask you what application to launch in this case you would use `gedit` then you can edit any file you want ( after entering your password of course )

> Could anyone point me to comprehensive tutorial on setting up a SIMPLE mysql-5.5 client-server system. Server: Ubuntu virtual machine, Client: Windows.

There are a ton of good tutorials on how to install mysql on Ubuntu. However if you are just using MySQL without the rest of the LAMP stack then I would suggest you look at [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) it will give you a graphical frontend to work with your server rather than having to use the command line, [PhpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) is also a good web-based tool but will require the rest of the LAMP stack installing and not just MySQL.

Comment: Thanks! I find a lot of tutorials indeed, who contradict or do things differently, and I run into basic errors for which I can't distinguish good from not good solutions. Leading me to a point where I feel my system is corrupted as hell by switching from tutorial to the next.